# How to provide a default bean in Spring by condition?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I'd like to provide a default bean by a custom jar. Only if the user implements a specific `abstract` class the default bean injection should be skipped.

The following setup already works fine, except one thing: any injected classes within the `default` wired class are `null`! What might I be missing?

```
@Configration
public class AppConfig {
    //use the default service if the user does not provide an own implementation
    @Bean
    @Conditional(MissingServiceBean.class)
    public MyService myService() {
        return new MyService() {};
    }
}


@Component
public abstract class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private SomeOtherService other;

    //default impl of the method, that may be overridden
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(other); //null! Why?
    }
}

public class MissingServiceBean implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return context.getBeanFactory().getBeansOfType(MyService.class).isEmpty();
    }
}
```

The `MyService` bean is created and can also be injected. But contained classes are null.

If I remove the `@Conditioanl` annotation everything works as expected.

Comment: With XML configuration you could do that, but that's not the way you want it right?

Comment: Right, I'd like to have annotation based config only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your simplest possibility is the usage of the `@Primary` annotation. You define your interface/abstract class and build a default implementation. Until here thats the basic spring autowiring.

Now you create another implementation with `@Primary` and make it available in the application context. Spring will now pick up the primary implementation for the autowiring.

---

Another possibilty in Spring 4.1+ would be to autowire an ordered `List<Intf>` and ask the interface with a `supports(...)` call to fetch the current implementation for whatever parameter you give into `supports`. You give the default implementation a `low priority` and the more detailed ones a higher priority. Like this you can even build a more detailed default behavior. I'm using this approach for several configurations to handle different classes with default and specific implementations.

One example would be during permission evaluation where we have a default config for the base classes, another higher one for domain classes, and a even higher possible one for specific domain entities. The permission evaluator goes through the list and checks each implementation if it supports that class and delegates to the implementation in that case.

I dont have the code here but i could share it later if desired to make that more clear.

Comment: I like the idea of `priorities` and will try it. But why is this approach restricted to 4.1+?

Comment: @membersound. The reason is that autowiring lists by the `Order` interface or annotation was not implemented before and i needed to write my own beanfactory at the time. Now wiring ordered lists is supported directly. It could be available at 4.0 already but i'm not sure, that's why i wrote 4.1+.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following:

```
public abstract class MyService {

    private final SomeOtherService other;

    public MyService(SomeOtherService other) {
       this.other = other;
    }

    //default impl of the method, that may be overridden
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(other);
    }
}

@Configration
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private SomeOtherService other;

    //use the default service if the user does not provide an own implementation
    @Bean
    @Condition(MissingServiceBean.class)
    public MyService myService() {
        return new MyService(other) {};
    }
}
```

Comment: OK that would work, but I'd prefer direct inject within the class. The question is why isn't this working with the `@Conditional` annotation. Because, if I remove the annotation, the internal services are all wired correctly.

Comment: @membersound My best guess would be that the existence of `Condition` does something internally that prevents `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` from working

Comment: @membersound Also there is a chance that `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` runs before the handling of `@Condition`. You would need to dig into the internals of Spring to see what's going on