# Spring: override annotated @Singleton definition

Tags: java, spring

**I've got** something like this:

```
@Named
@Singleton
public class MyDefaultDef {

  @Inject
  public MyDefaultDef(SomeRef someRef, List<AnotherRef> anotherRefs) {
    //...
  }
  //...
}
```

**Question:** *How to make an heir of `MyDefaultDef` that will override `MyDefaultDef` definition?* Means `@Autowired MyDefaultDef` should return `MyDefaultDefHeir`.

**Updated: (In other words)**

I need `SomeService` injected `MyDefaultDefHeir` instead of `MyDefaultDef`

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

 @Inject
 public SomeService(MyDefaultDef myDefaultDef) {
  //...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you search is this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25528379/869225

You can use `@Primary` or an ordered list to achieve what you want.

Comment: that doesn't work. If you'd add `@Primary` to `MyDefaultDefHeir` than `SomeService` inject `MyDefaultDef` instead of `MyDefaultDefHeir`. Maybe I understand you wrong, can you provide an example pls?

Comment: Service + Primary clearly works. Are you sure both beans are in the spring context? If you have both and no primary spring fails to load the context with a DuplicateBeanException.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be using a mix of JSR-330 (@Inject) and Springs own annotations (@Autowired) here.

If you want to use `@Autowired`

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myDefaultDefHeir")
```

or if you want to use `@Inject`

```
@Inject
@Named("myDefaultDefHair")
```

Is this what you are looking for?